# Where can I find the English translation of Parashara Smriti?

Tags: dharma-shastras, resource, parashara-smriti

People say that Parashara Smriti is for Kali Yuga. So it is no doubt an important text. Is there any English translation available?

Comment: It can be downloaded from here (https://www.indiadivine.org/content/files/file/17-sri-parashara-smriti-with-english-translation-pdf/) among other places. This is an extremely trivial question btw (can be answered by just a Google search).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link everyone is sharing is not a published book. Someone created that document. The only published translation of Parashara Smriti that I could find is part of the following book

The Dharma Sastra or The Hindu Law Codes (English Translation) Vol. II by Manmatha Nath Dutt (Shastri).

Apart from Parasar Samhita, it also contains translations of Sankha, Gautama, Apastamba and Vashistha Samhitas.

Link -

https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.31797/page/n5/mode/2up

Comment: "The link everyone is sharing is not a published book" -- where is your question asking for a published book? All it asks for is an English translation.

Comment: @Rickross When someone asks for a translation, it is pretty evident that he means an authentic translation done by some expert in that field, not by any Tom, Dick and Harry.

Comment: How can a tom dick or a harry translate Parshara Smriti? Is it that trivial a task?

Comment: @Rickross Anybody can type anything and make a pdf. There is no way to know whether that homemade pdf contains an authentic translation. But anyway, if you like that homemade pdf document, I have no problem.

Answer (score 0):

Parashara Smriti can be read and downloaded from here [1](https://archive.org/details/ParasharaSmriti/mode/2up).

Answer (score 0):

You can find it [here](https://archive.org/stream/ParasharaSmriti/SriParasharaSmrithiPdf_djvu.txt)

While the Parashara Smriti applies to Kali Yuga it probably doesn't mean this one.

The Parashara Smriti may be canon scripture, but it says some things that would be insane to actually apply in this world, such as:

> If a woman meets not her lord, on the day that her
>
> monthly courses stop, — she after death goes to hell, — and
>
> becomes a widow in repeated births.

> If the husband meets not his wife on the day that
> her monthly courses cease, and she be near at hand, he
> incurs the awful sin of having killed a foetus. There is
> not the slightest doubt herein.

There are literally thousands of reasons why this would cause havoc as this sin has no repentance. E.g. quarantine, work, hospital admission.